# Django - include another html file from different location

Tags: html, django

I have two htmls a.html and b.html. a.html is located in the template folder by default. b.html is located in appname/static/images/b.html, because it's a model calculation result in html format.

In a.html, I am trying to include b.html but it's not working, unless b.html is in the same template folder.

```
<body>
  {% include 'appname/static/images/b.html' %}
</body>
```

questions:

1. how to include b.html?
2. how to include b.html dynamically if it's in different folder, e.g. images/username/b.html where username is different.

Comment: Django is pretty strict about where you place your template files. You can set the template directory in `settings.py`. Please refer to the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/overriding-templates/). That being said, do you have control regarding which format the model calculation result is generated? I think an API serving the model results as JSON responses is more appropriate than generating an HTML file.

Comment: it's an interactive graph which has to be html format. I read the doc and follow the instruction, django constantly does not find the format even I changed the path. could you please offer a help to show the codes

Comment: Assuming you have the following config `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']`, then you would place the html in `<BASE_DIR>/templates/appname/static/images/b.html`. Alternatively, if you have `APP_DIRS` set to True, then place your html in `<BASE_DIR>/appname/templates/appname/static/images/b.html`. You can't arbitrarily place the template files anywhere and expect django to fetch them dynamically. It's really strict with where to search for template files.

Comment: so in whatever ways it has to be in a subdirectory of the templates folder? this is really inflexible...

Comment: Yea, that's why going the template route might not be the best option. That being said, if your html file is generated by a model and it doesn't use any context variables, you could just read the file into a string and then return a [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) with the string as the content.

Comment: could you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimum viable example using the `HttpResponse` method:

```py
from pathlib import Path

from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse


def my_view(request):
    my_html = settings.BASE_DIR / "appname" / "static" / "images" / "b.html"

    with my_html.open() as f:
        content = f.read()

    return HttpResponse(content)
```